# MySQL specific query requirement and data transferring

Tags: phpmyadmin

we have two tables users having id `f_name,l_name,address,contact` and we have second table `users_vs(id,first_user_id,second_user_id)` how we will by submitting value of users form value how we can get in the second table record like this in first 2 entries first_user_id having 1, second_user_id having 2 and so on also draw the structure please help in query.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, it's not clear what you are asking. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Second, what have to tried so far? We're here to help you with code that you wrote. We're not here to write code for you.

Comment: Code mark up and fix spelling